# Possible to have WinKey + Number equivalent in Mac for faster app switching

Tags: shortcut

In windows we can easily switch/open an app in the taskbar by doing `WinKey + <order of the app in the taskbar>` (e.g. WinKey+1 will open/switch the 1st app)

Just to provide more context. I'm looking for a way to quickly switch to an app in the dock. Let's say I have the following apps in order:

```
1 - Finder
2 - Calendar
3 - Notes
```

I'm looking for a way to easily switch to Notes just by doing `WinKey + 3` but in Mac equivalent.

Cause right now, the available options that I'm aware of are:

1. `Command` + `Tab`
2. By using the mouse to navigate to the app which takes a hand of the keyboard.

Comment: Just because a program is shown in the dock does not mean it is running... So if Notes is not running do you expect it to be started?

Comment: I would assume so since I'm trying to switch into that program regardless if it's running or not.

Comment: Then that is not just “switching” between apps is it.

Comment: If I'm in the Calendar and I do this magic command to open the Notes. For me, that is "switching into" the Notes program from Calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out about [Snap](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/snap/id418073146?mt=12). I may not have a Mac machine with me right now but this seems to fit what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I use command with tab.

Brings up a bar with the icons of running apps and you tab through to the one you want. Command Q and command W also work to close apps or windows.

Comment: I'm aware of that, it's like the Alt+Tab of Windows but unfortunately it is not the answer to my question. I want to be able to directly switch to an app in the dock.